# Dijkstra's algorithm - paradox

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I am solving next Dijkstra's algorithm. [image]

S - start, T - final.
In first step I choose $C(102)$.
Next step I choose $E(187)$.
Third step I choose $G(304)$ because it is less than $F(310)$.
Then from $G$ I can go only to $T(426)$
Paradox is that if I go from $E$ to $F$ and then $T$ path is shorter, but I do not know that in $E$ position. How can I solve this using algorithm. Should I do backwards checks from $T$ to $F$ and $G$, or I miss anything?

Comment: I do not see what is paradox about this result. The sum of the distances EF and FT is smaller than the sum of the distances EG and GT. Always choosing the smallest next distance need not lead to the optimal way.

Comment: Not sure whether the problem is NP-complete.

Comment: @Peter what that means

Comment: Basically, that there is no efficient way to solve it.

Comment: @Peter so I must calculate it without table I am using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no paradox, you are simply not applying the algorithm in its entirety. Just because $B$ is further away than $C$ at the first step doesn't mean that you disregard it forever.

You need to consider each and every path and keep track of the shortest way to get to **every** point in the graph, so that in the end, **in particular** you have the shortest path leading to the goal.

Example of the induction step in the algorithm: you know the shortest path to go to $B$ and also to go to $C$. Now to go to $E$

- either you go from $C$
- or you go from $B$
- (or you go from $B$ through $F$ but this will be taken care of later)

So keep the shortest of these two ways. Now you have two ways to go to $F$, from $B$ or from $E$. If the shortest path to $F$ was from $B$ you might have to update the shortest path to $E$ (eg if instead of $195$ and $123$ you had $1$ and $2$).

Comment: Please follow my steps: S, C, E. Then what must I do next? I have choose to go to G. Is that correct or not? Please read my question

Comment: You have to consider all possibilities at all times and write down what is the shortest path to go to $G$ but also what is the shortest path to go to $F$.

Comment: Yes I already did that. I know shortest path to E, so that means shortest path to G is SCEG and shortest to F is SCEF. What we do from here?

Comment: From there, see which is shorter between SCEG+122 and SCEF+101 :)

Comment: SCEG+117 SCEF+123 you tell me, Should I go to G of F?

Comment: You tell me that you know the shortest path to $G$ and it is SCEG. Now what is the length of this path? Call it x(G).
Similarly call x(F) the shortest path to $F$. Then the shortest path to $T$ is MIN(x(G)+117, x(F)+123).
That is what the algorithm does.

Answer (score 2):

Your stated algorithm is not Dijkstra's Algorithm.

For the real Dijkstra's Algorithm, every time a vertex is processed, the neighboring vertices also have to be updated. And every time we must select a vertex, we should select the one with minimum distance processed but still active.

Your algorithm was a greedy algorithm which turns to fail in this case.